# Can I use Google colab without saving the notebook to Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-colab

Sometimes when using [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) I don't need to keep the resulting notebook. I'd like to use colab as a scratchpad, rather than cluttering the Google Drive in my account with `UntitledXX.ipynb` files.

Is there a way to use colab as a scratchpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way! Visit http://colab.to to have an ephemeral notebook that doesn't result in cluttering your Google Drive.